ArgoCD github repository connection fails, error: Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: authentication required
Trying to connect a github repo I have admin access to ArgoCD with my credentials:
argocd repo add https://github.com/myuser/myrepo --username myuser --password mypass

But I keep getting error:
FATA[0000] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: authentication required

If I try through UI I get error:

If I check the argocd-repo-server it has exact same error as:
argocd-repo-server level=error msg="finished unary call with code 
Unknown" error="error testing repository connectivity: authentication required" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.method=Test
Repository grpc.service=repository.RepoServerService 


I did some investigation and also test it in my environment, which getting the same error you got.
Your issue is related to 2FA is enable in your GitHub account, so the only option you have is to use personal access tokens(PAT), here is official GitHub link how to create PAT token. when you had your PAT token run this command:
argocd repo add https://github.com/myuser/myrepo --username <YOUR_USERNAME_HERE> --password <YOUR_PAT_TOKEN>


In my case, this problem happens when the project has no default (scoped) repository.
So try to configure you repository as the default repository for the project to which your application is assigned.
